# Rails to_json method with associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There is the following code:

```
@menu.to_json(include: [:submenus])
```

I get a JSON respresentation of menu with submenus. But submenu has association 'items', and I want to render menu with all the submenus and with all the items. How can I do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matching the format you originally used, I think you can nest them like this:

```
@menu.to_json(include: {submenus: {include: :items}})
```

Also, check out this post from the creators of RABL: http://blog.thecodepath.com/2011/05/16/if-youre-using-to_json-youre-doing-it-wrong/

Answer (score 1):

You can also take a look at RABL (https://github.com/nesquena/rabl)